# Do I need to validate data uses for querying in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In the snippet below, do I need to validate that the user did in fact enter an email or at least alpha-numeric characters? I'm not concerned about a valid input, I'm just thinking if there is a security vulnerability in querying the database with raw input data:

```
$user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();
```

Comment: In case you are worried about SQL injections, there's no need to be. Laravel uses prepared statements which prevents SQL injections of any kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to do validation in this case. Laravel will escape your SQL query.

The user's input either matches an existing email in the database or it doesn't.

There's no security risk involved. Validation is redundant here.

Comment: What about inserts from `Request` object?

Answer (score 1):

To check if a user entered a 'real' email you could use a validator

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array(
        'email' => 'required|email'
    )
);
```

// if its fails

```
   if ($validator->fails())
    {
        // The given data did not pass validation
    }
```

More about validation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation